# Spring MVC getting The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i have migrated spring 3 to 4 . i am getting below error while uploading file Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String DataController.submitfile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)

Comment: Give some relevant code. Help others who are are trying to help you.

Comment: this is the method using for file upload in controller 
@ResponseBody
 @RequestMapping(value = "/submitfile/{reportType}", method = RequestMethod.POST,
 consumes = "text/csv", produces = "text/plain")
 public String submitfile(@RequestBody String incomingCSV,@PathVariable String reportType,
 @RequestHeader("Auth") String autho,HttpServletResponse response) {

        
  
  ............
  }

Comment: How you are sending file to server?

Comment: sORRY FOR THE LATE REPLAY..

Comment: I am uploading file Through SoupUI